# Magento 2 get CMS page url and output it to a html file

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, geturl

I have the following code in a html file.

```
<div><span data-bind="i18n: 'insurance condition'"></span> <a href="https://example.com/index.php/sales-and-delivery-terms" target="_blank" data-bind="i18n: 'condition link'"></a></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="extra_fee_flag" class="checkbox" id="extra_fee_flag" value="1"/>
<span data-bind="text: getExtraFeeLabel()"></span>
<span> &nbsp; + </span>
<span data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice()" class="price" style="font-weight: 600"></span>
```

in the A tag, I have a hardcoded link to the **sales and condition** page which is a CMS block. How can I get the url of this page dynamatically so even one day the url is change in the admin, this link will still be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('my_page_url_key');?>">Link to my page</a>
```